# Tool to start ArcGIS for Server services automatically?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, services

Is there any tools or scripts to start ArcGIS server 10.1 services automatically when the services are stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found [Example: Stop or start all services in a folder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000005qv000000) . It was very useful for the purpose . If you want to start automatically just change some of items in this sample and run in **task scheduler** of windows .

Answer (score 2):

It should be fairly simple:

- Use a tool to monitor the ArcGIS service. For example Nagios or a member of its ilk.
- When the service ceases to respond, have a script run automatically (such as the one you found) that restarts it.

Comment: I disagree. Its sysadmin if it was the ArcGIS Server service, but the Q is around the individual services within ArcGIS for Server.  Wetlands own answer is correct. The ArcGIS Server Admin API allows you to start/stop services, which only someone experienced with ArcGIS Server would know.  But, agree with your recommendation for Nagios.

Comment: I agree with @Simon - and since it is more of a comment than a direct answer to the question will edit to remove it.  Without the comment I am happy to upvote the remainder of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting ArcGIS service involves using ArcGIS Rest Admin API and ability to authenticate using token-based authentication with ArcGIS server. One way to do it is to write a script/program to monitor the ArcGIS Service and in the event service is found stopped restart it , schedule it to run periodically. But it gets cumbersome when you have to monitor more and more services and servers. As far as I know, iGeoAsset is the only tool available that has the capability to monitor an ArcGIS server service and restart it automatically via token-based authentication.

http://www10.giscafe.com/nbc/articles/view_article.php?articleid=1345727